# Save is not a function in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm doing a ticketing API using **NodeJS + ExpressJS** . In a PUT method to modify a ticket that has been created before I have the next error.

**Error**

```
/home/ismael/projects/nodejs-ticketing/routes/ticket.js:38
      item.save(function(err){
           ^

TypeError: item.save is not a function
    at /home/ismael/projects/nodejs-ticketing/routes/ticket.js:38:12
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ismael/projects/nodejs-ticketing/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2169:28)
    at /home/ismael/projects/nodejs-ticketing/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /home/ismael/projects/nodejs-ticketing/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The function I call to modify the ticket is the next one:

**ticket.js**

```
  _modifyPutTicket = function(req, res){
    var query = Ticket.findOne().where('issue').equals(req.params.issue).lean();

    log.debug( 'New data: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body) );

    query.exec(function(err, item){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      log.debug( 'Issue: ' + JSON.stringify(item) );

      item.title          = req.body.title;
      item.description    = req.body.description;

      log.debug( 'Issue modified: ' + JSON.stringify(item) );

      item.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          log.debug( 'Issue error: ' + err );

          res.send(err);
        }else{
          res.send(item);
        }
      });
    });
  };

app.put('/api/ticket/:issue/', _modifyPutTicket);
```

I followed the mongoose tutorial to update a document stored in a `MongoDB`. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of lean() when building the query. Documents found using lean are returned as Javascript objects instead of full Mongoose documents, and don't have any getters/setters.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean